# Splitting a pdf with pdfbox, but losing the font

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox

I wrote some code in Java using the pdfbox API that splits a pdf document into it's individual pages, looks through the pages for a specific string, and then makes a new pdf from the page with the string on it.  My problem is that when the new page is saved, I lose my font.  I just made a quick word document to test it and the default font was calibri, so when I run the program I get an error box that reads: "Cannot extract the embedded font..." So it replaces the font with some other default.

I have seen a lot of example code that shows how to change the font when you are inputting text to be placed in the pdf, but nothing that sets the font for the pdf.

If anyone is familiar with a way to do this, (or can find documentation/examples), I would greatly appreciate it!

Edit: forgot to include some sample code

```
if (pageContent.indexOf(findThis) >= 0){
                PDPage pageToRip = pages.get(i);
                >>set the font of pageToRip here
                res.importPage(pageToRip); //res is the new document that will be saved
            }
```

I don't know if that helps any, but I figured I'd include it.

Also, this is what the change looks like if the pdf is written in calibri and split:

[image: left:calibri, right:what it changes to]

**Note: This might be a nonissue, it depends on the font used in the files that will need to be processed.  I tried some things besides Calibri and it worked out fine.**

Comment: Would setting it to change to Calibri work? (Through the example codes you've seen) Since you can't set it, setting it to change to the font you want should be similar in my thinking.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I can't find any documentation on how to change the font of something I'm saving.  I'm simply cutting a page out of a pdf and putting it in a a new document.  The font changing stuff that I've seen is just for adding strings to a pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [How to extract fonts from a PDF](http://www.prepressure.com/pdf/basics/fonts):

> You actually cannot extract a font from a PDF, not even if the font is
>   fully embedded. There are two reasons why this is not feasible:
>
> •Most fonts are copyrighted, making it illegal to use an extractor.
>
> •When a font is embedded in a PDF, not all of the font data are
>   included. Obviously the font outline data are included as well as the
>   font width tables. Other information, such as data about ligatures,
>   are irrelevant within the PDF so those data do not get enclosed in a
>   PDF. I am not aware of any font extraction tools but if you come
>   across one, the above reasons should make it clear that these
>   utilities are to be avoided.

Comment: It does and it doesn't, I figured that'd be the case for most fonts, but pdfbox does have some default fonts that you can use and there is also the capability to import.  I'd be fine with using a default font, likes TNR, but it's switching it to something strange and unsightly.

Comment: Strange and unsightly...? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Sure I will add a screenshot to the original question.  When I copy and paste the new text into word, it says it is displaying Arial, but it clearly is not, or is not properly displaying it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah it's probably just that text, some texts have issues.